# Front end entry dropdown with null option

Tags: matrix, entries-field, frontend-form

I have successfully implemented a front-end form that allows the user to add new "blocks" to a certain matrix field. This matrix field has one text field, two date fields, and one entry field that links to one specific entry type: `sites`.

**How can I add an option to the dropdown list that would allow the user to "ignore" this field as if they left it alone when adding data in the admin area?**

Here is what I have tried:

```
<select name="fields[scriptLots][new1][fields][lotSite][]">
    <option value="">No Site</option>
    {% for site in sites.order('title') %}
        <option value="{{site.id}}">{{site.title}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I figured just adding an option tag ahead of the `for` loop with no value would do the trick. However this just responds in a major error:

```
CDbException: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dsi_craft_vetscripts`.`craft_relations`, CONSTRAINT `craft_relations_targetId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`targetId`) REFERENCES `craft_elements` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_relations` (`fieldId`, `sourceId`, `sourceLocale`, `targetId`, `sortOrder`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated`, `uid`) VALUES (:row0_col0, :row0_col1, NULL, :row0_col3, :row0_col4, :row0_col5, :row0_col6, :row0_col7). Bound with :row0_col0='54', :row0_col1='3382', :row0_col3='', :row0_col4=1, :row0_col5='2017-11-07 15:26:00', :row0_col6='2017-11-07 15:26:00', :row0_col7='06895bfe-d902-49f6-a085-bd080f68cdef'
```

So that empty value attribute seems to be breaking something. How can I add a null option?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that. Every entry must be linked to a site. You can't include a "null" option. You would have to alter the table and change the default query since they are related to the siteId. If an entry is not related to a site you would not be able to display it in the backend cp. You can only add a default site to it

Comment: What you could do is creating another site as your "null" value and hide this one in your cp via permissions or via a plugin. But those entries won't make it to the frontend unless you specify it in twig